# WPF Change icon depending on binding in Control Template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a control template that I've defined for a DevExpress TextEdit control and I want to change the Image **Source** property in the template depending on a binding (e.g. IsIncrease).

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="WarningTextEdit" TargetType="dxe:TextEdit">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
            <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                   Source="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v17.2;component/Core/ConditionalFormatting/Images/IconSets/Symbols3_2.png" 
                   Width="17" 
                   Height="16"
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"   
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

If the property IsIncrease was set to true then one particular icon should be shown and if the property was set to false then another particular icon should be shown. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a converter, you have two choices, either you include 2 `Image`s inside your `Grid` and you hide/show them using the converter or you use one `Image` and use the converter to change the `Source` property (which is probably a better solution). Here's a converter that can handle both situation, followed by both solutions.

BoolConverter :

```
public class BoolConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object TrueValue { get; set; } = Binding.DoNothing;
    public object FalseValue { get; set; } = Binding.DoNothing;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool))
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == TrueValue)
            return true;

        if (value == FalseValue)
            return false;

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml (solution 1 : two `Image`s) :

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="WarningTextEdit" TargetType="dxe:TextEdit">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                       Source="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v17.2;component/Core/ConditionalFormatting/Images/IconSets/Symbols3_2.png" 
                       Width="17" 
                       Height="16"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"   
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Visibility="{Binding IsIncrease, Converter={local:BoolConverter TrueValue=Collapsed, FalseValue=Visible}}"/>
                <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                       Source="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v17.2;component/Core/ConditionalFormatting/Images/IconSets/TrafficLights3_1.png" 
                       Width="17" 
                       Height="16"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"   
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Visibility="{Binding IsIncrease, Converter={local:BoolConverter TrueValue=Visible, FalseValue=Collapsed}}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

MainWindow.xaml (solution 2 : one `Image`) :

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="WarningTextEdit" TargetType="dxe:TextEdit">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                       Source="{Binding IsIncrease, 
                                        Converter={local:BoolConverter TrueValue='pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v17.2;component/Core/ConditionalFormatting/Images/IconSets/Symbols3_2.png', 
                                                                       FalseValue='pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v17.2;component/Core/ConditionalFormatting/Images/IconSets/TrafficLights3_1.png'}}" 
                       Width="17" 
                       Height="16"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"   
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks Roger! I like this one so going with this. My next question is how would I make this control template re-useable so that I can bind to IsIncrease?

For e.g. 

<dxe:TextEdit Text ="{Binding InvestmentValue}" IsIncrease = "{Binding AssetsIncreased}" Template="{StaticResource WarningTextEdit}"></dxe:TextEdit>

<dxe:TextEdit Text ="{Binding CashValue}" IsIncrease = "{Binding AssetsIncreased}" Template="{StaticResource WarningTextEdit}"></dxe:TextEdit>

Comment: Nevermind I managed to solve this one myself!

I added an attached property in code and added this to my control template

Comment: public class WarningHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsWarning = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsWarning", typeof(bool), typeof(WarningHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public static void SetIsWarning(DependencyObject target, bool value)
        {
            target.SetValue(IsWarning, value);
        }

        public static bool GetIsWarning(DependencyObject target)
        {
            return (bool)target.GetValue(IsWarning);
        }
    }

Comment: Source="{Binding Path=(attachedProperties:WarningHelper.IsWarning), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                        Converter={converters:BoolConverter TrueValue='pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v17.2;component/Core/ConditionalFormatting/Images/IconSets/Symbols3_2.png', 
                                                                       FalseValue='pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v17.2;component/Core/ConditionalFormatting/Images/IconSets/TrafficLights3_1.png'}}"

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need 2 properties to store source for image.I'm gonna use Tag property and write an attached property to store 2 image source and use trigger to change the source

```
   public class AttachedProperty
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AltSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AltSource",
        typeof(string), typeof(AttachedProperty),
        new PropertyMetadata());

    public static string GetAltSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(AltSourceProperty);
    }
    public static void SetAltSource(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AltSourceProperty, value);
    }
}
```

ControlTemplate

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="WarningTextEdit" TargetType="dxe:TextEdit">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                <Image x:Name="image"
                       Width="17"
                       Height="16"
                       Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsIncrease " Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsIncrease " Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=(local:AttachedProperty.AltSource), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>



<dxe:TextEdit Tag="Image1.jpg" local:AttachedProperty.AltSource="Image2.jpg"/>
```